# Set value of each DataTable row in specific column

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem while trying to set column value.

I'v had a dataTable which get some values from SQL and then im adding two new columns by :

```
        dataTable.Columns.Add("dest", typeof(int));

        dataTable.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));
```

Which works great but now i want to put 0 in every row in column name dest - and later user will edit this, and then i want to set amount value as

```
       amount = all(this column is in dataTable before I add these 2 columns) + dest;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int columnNumber = 5; //Put your column X number here

for (int i = 0; i < yourDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    yourDataTable.Rows[i][columnNumber] = "0"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will solve this second problem with exacly this same thing. :)

Comment: @Pro100 Not to worry - please marked as accepted as soon as you can. I'm 2 points from a medal, and shamelessly want it :p

Comment: Yea I wanted to before I coment :P  but it tells me I had to wait 7more mins.

Comment: @Pro100 You're a star! I have until UTC midnight, so it's okay :)

Comment: So what's that medal you received? curious to know by seeing your comment.

Comment: It will be the 200 rep for 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` too.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
     //if (row["X"] has condition) // or if any condition
         row["colName"] = row[colIndex] = "abc";
```